# how to get inserted sequential uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

my table looks like this:

```
create table foos(
id uniqueidentifier primary KEY DEFAULT (newsequentialid()),
..
)
```

so the id is sequentially generated automatically, I'm not setting it

how do I get it's value after the insert ? 
(with identity I was doing `insert ... select @@identity`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Returning the NewSequentialID() after Insert using the Output Clause](http://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/returning-the-newsequentialid-after-insert-using-the-output-clause/)

The basic idea:

```
create table foos(id uniqueidentifier primary KEY DEFAULT (newsequentialid()))

declare @Ids table(id uniqueidentifier)

insert foos
output inserted.id into @Ids
default values

select *
from @Ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to use one auxiliar table, you can think about some temp table... This is one possible solution:

```
DECLARE @NewId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @MyTableOutput TABLE
(
    AuxId int NOT NULL
    ,NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
)
INSERT INTO @MyTableOutput (AuxId) VALUES (1)
SELECT @NewId = NewID FROM @MyTableOutput
DELETE FROM @MyTableOutput
```

So you get your NewId to use in your INSERT, will work as one GEN_ID()

```
INSERT INTO MyTableFoos(MyId, MyValue...) VALUES (@NewId,'MyValue'...)
```

Your DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() will be on your TempTable, and your real table let without DEFAULT to your UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Answer (score -1):

You would use the other data that got inserted with the id to select it out again.  So where you have the `..` you would have:

```
SELECT id
WHERE ..
```

which would return the id