# SELECT @@IDENTITY giving Specified Cast is not Valid?

Tags: c#, guid

hope someone can help with this

I am trying to INSERT a row of data into table [Issues] then immediately get the Guid from the ID column of Issues so it can be inserted into another table Actions, creating a link between the two. The relationship is [Issues]one to many[Actions].

When I run this code it causes a Specified Cast is not valid error here:
Guid lastID = (Guid)sel.ExecuteScalar();

lastID is the variable I want to assign the last Guid created to so it can be passed into another table INSERT for table Actions.

If anyone can help that would be great! Thanks

I am using C# 2010 Express

```
//This is declared at the top of the form
public Guid lastID;

        private void pbSaveIssue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        SqlCeConnection ArcBaseConn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ArcBase.sdf");

        try
        {
            string cmdIssueSubmit = "INSERT INTO Issues (Type,Description,Dateraised,Site,Reportedby,Status) VALUES (@Type,@Description,@Dateraised,@Site,@Reportedby,@Status)";
            string TypeSubmit = cbIssueType.Text;
            string DescriptionSubmit = rtbDescription.Text;
            string SiteSubmit = cbIssueSite.Text;
            string ReportedbySubmit = cbReportedBy.Text;
            string DateraisedSubmit = dtpDateRaised.Text;

            SqlCeCommand sel = new SqlCeCommand();
            sel.Connection = ArcBaseConn;
            sel.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sel.CommandText = cmdIssueSubmit;
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", TypeSubmit);
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DescriptionSubmit);
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateraised", DateraisedSubmit);
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", SiteSubmit);
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reportedby", ReportedbySubmit);
            sel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", lbStatus.Text);

            ArcBaseConn.Open();
            sel.ExecuteNonQuery();


            //Here is the problem

            // Grab the last Unique ID for the Issue just entered and assign to a variable so that it can be entered with the Actions below.
            string cmdGetlastID = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
            sel.CommandText=cmdGetlastID;

            Guid lastID = (Guid)sel.ExecuteScalar();
            ArcBaseConn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.ExitThread();
        }
```

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` returns a number - it will not return a GUID.  You'll need to capture the guid with an `OUTPUT` clause in your INSERT statement.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262222/how-to-get-inserted-sequential-uniqueidentifier) for an example.

Comment: Thanks D Stanley, that's one of the things I've tried. The INSERT command I tried was string cmdIssueSubmit = "INSERT INTO Issues (Type,Description,Dateraised,Site,Reportedby,Status) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (@Type,@Description,@Dateraised,@Site,@Reportedby,@Status)";"but it return a token error for OUTPUT

Comment: Stop using `Select @@IDENTITY `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table your are inserting into has an identity column defined,

- Identity columns must be integer types (`tinyint`, `smallint`, `int` or `bigint`), not `Guid`, so casting to a `Guid` won't work (as you discovered).
- You probably want to use `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead of `@@IDENTITY`, lest you discover the pain caused by race conditions.

From the looks of your code, you aren't doing this, but...

If you are trying to get the value of a column defined as `uniqueid` (and do it so you don't have a race condition), you need to do something like this:

```
declare @my_guid uniqueid = newid()

INSERT Issues
(
  Type        ,
  Description ,
  Dateraised  ,
  Site        ,
  Reportedby  ,
  Status       ,
  Unique_Guid_Column
)
VALUES
(
  @Type        ,
  @Description ,
  @Dateraised  ,
  @Site        ,
  @Reportedby  ,
  @Status      ,
  @my_guid
)

select case @@ERROR when 0 then @myguid else null end
```

And then execute that using `ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: Hi, yes the Issues table has the ID column set as type Uniqueidentfier and Is rowGuid is True. The insert command does successfully generate a guid in the table. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Would it be possible for someone to add the suggested code by Nicolas into my code as I am new of SQL and have not seen this type of string query format. All I am familiar with is the one liners for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. I would really appreciate the assistance! thanks